# How to read large files from google drive into gae blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, blobstore

This is the code that I'm currently using to read files from google drive into the blobstore of google app engine.

```
private BlobKey getBlobKey(File f, DriveObject driveObject)
            throws IOException, MalformedURLException { 

        Drive service = ((GoogleDrive) driveObject).getService();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) f.getFileSize().intValue()];
        GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(f.getDownloadUrl());
        HttpResponse response = service.getRequestFactory()
                    .buildGetRequest(url).execute();

        InputStream is = response.getContent();

        FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
        AppEngineFile file = null;
        boolean lock = true;
        try {
            file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("application/zip");
            FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(
                        file, lock);

            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer, 0, len);
            writeChannel.write(bb);
            }
            writeChannel.closeFinally();

        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            BlobKey bk = fileService.getBlobKey(file);

        return bk;
    }
```

This works fine for small files but it gives an error if the file is more that ~25MB.  Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

This is the error I see

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.ResponseTooLargeException: The response from url https://doc-0o-bs-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/97o44sjeam7f23b1flie9m3qqidhrago/97q4akk8bmpub24itqhclo1vakjusu84/1368259200000/14350098165097390874/14350098165097390874/0ByS2XCxCEzq-NUVuajAwWGVoR1U?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true was too large.
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:132)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.fetchResponse(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:417)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getInputStream(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:296)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection.getResponseCode(URLFetchServiceStreamHandler.java:149)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:95)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:980)
```

I should add that

```
Drive service = ((GoogleDrive) driveObject).getService();
```

returns

```
new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, cred)
            .build()
```

Comment: App Engine restricts the size of HTTP message bodies.

Comment: I realise that's what's going on but is there no way around this?  It's pretty crucial that I can read large files into the blobstore.  Maybe I need to read it in multiple messages.

Comment: I can upload the files I need from my computer via a blobstoreservice but this is not good enoough as I need to be able to do it via the drive interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the file from Drive in chunks. Use the [Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) header in your download request as documented in the [Google Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads).

```
Range: bytes=500-999
```

Comment: Nate that there is still quota an the number of bytes you can download.  I'm currently getting a `urlfetch.Fetch()` exception at around the 50MB mark.  (Note that I'm not a paying user. :-)  See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#UrlFetch

Answer (score 0):

This FilsService & FileWriteChannel api has been deprecated in favor of the App Engine GCS client.